# show rows with a relation before in Laravel

Tags: laravel, subquery, sql-order-by, laravel-query-builder

in a Laravel application, I have a list of `companies`. Some of those are related to a `subscriptions` table in a `1 x n relation`.

I want to order the companies in a way that the ones which have a subscription appear before the ones which have no subscription using just one db query.

Any idea is much appreciated!

thanks!

Comment: A company can have many subscriptions? Thats the relation?

Comment: well, technically it can, since the subscription lasts one year :). But I don't think that's relevant :)

Comment: I am asking because that way i tell you what kind of query you can make. Tel me the exact relation beetween them.

Comment: as I said, yes, a company can have more than one subscription.

Answer (score 0):

Laravel uses separate queries to eager load relationships. So if you want to do this you will need to join the tables and order by...

Something in the form...

```
$companies = App\Companies::join('subscriptions as sub', 'sub.company_id', '=', 'company.id')
    ->orderBy('sub.somefield', 'DESC')
    ->select(what you need)
    ->with('if you need the relation data');
```

You know you can also only query those records that have a relationship with

```
$companies = App\Companies::has('subscription')->get();
```

Maybe that is all you need... and

```
$companies = App\Companies::doesntHave('subscription')->get();
```

... returns the opposite where the company has no subscription...